# 1977 GE 6RS20SP9B9 - what the heck is this component?

Tags: diodes, vintage, mov, varicap

Ok so, ordinarily I'd not ask a "what is this" question, but this component really has me scratching my head - both at its function in the circuit and how it is constructed.  Anyone know what a GE 6RS20SP9B9 axial device, circa 1977, is?

[image: GE 6RS20SP9B9]

The only [datasheet](http://datasheet.datasheetarchive.com/originals/distributors/Datasheets-X/Document-242.pdf) I could find goes up to a 6RS20SP8B8. The *xBx series, according to this datasheet, seem to be "tunnel, vari-cap, and voltage-sensitive diodes."  Funny thing is, this device (along with a beefy resistor and cap as snubber) is directly across a 120vAC, 30A dual-SCR bus. So it is *intended* to be a MOV I believe, or at least perform the function of a MOV. Can anyone shed some light on this device and why it was used in the circuit?

Initial measurements (device was already falling apart) seemed to indicate it was slightly capacitive and slightly diode-like. The 19 little metal discs are coated in a blue/green substance. Some are more gray than others, possibly from wear. Measuring one of the discs inside with a Fluke 175:

- vDC: 10mV / -20mV (variable on pressure and contact area)
- Ohms: 170k / 15M
- Cap: 0nF / 27nF

**EDIT:**

So I took @winny's advice and sampled one of the 19 internal discs and plotted I/V curves. Current on left, voltage on right.

[image: Parameterizing one of 19 discs inside a GE 6RS20SP9B9]

A disc was cleaned with IPA. A tiny bit of the green color came off so it was washed quickly. But none of the "grey" was removed at all. To apply pressure to the disc and make contact to both sides, it was covered in paper and clamped in "helping hands" with the original leads.

[image: How the disc was tested.]

Here is the resulting data:

[image: Plot of voltage and current for both forward and reverse.]

The discs are definitely rectifiers, perhaps selenium. The "reverse" characteristic is mostly logarithmic, and testing the upper ranges was tricky as a strong positive temperature coefficient was observed. (Is this typical breakdown behavior for selenium?)

The "forward" characteristic is very diode-like, however shows a mostly linear response. Perhaps this could be improved by better clamping. "Forward" didn't seem to have a temp-co at all.

So... if 19 of these are stacked together, in an alternating fashion... then that would more-or-less make a high-voltage, avalanche-mode equivalent to a modern MOV!

Comment: That's a GE / General Electric logo on the capacitor like thing, if it helps.

Comment: Far fetch but a MOV? Can you sactifice one disc and plot a V-I-curve for it a power supply?

Comment: http://www.parttarget.com/6130-00-136-1416_6130001361416_KZ9DTM.html/-F6E88022-6182-406B-9D13-B5E96B53FAE0

Maybe this information about multiple manufacturers might help: 6RS20SP9B9 General Electric Co, 6RS20SP9B9 Dean Technology Inc, KZ9DTM International Rectifier Corporation

Comment: Looks like a capacitor to me.  That's the kind with two strips of thin foil with mylar insulator wrapped in a roll, and molded into some rigid plastic.  It's one step up from the foil and wax paper capacitors of the previous generation.

Comment: Looks like a wax-dipped paper capacitor to me, but Olin may be right. Is it as late as 1977?

Comment: maybe a TVS, unidirectional https://www.ebay.ca/itm/GENERAL-ELECTRIC-6RS20SP9B9-Used-Cleaned-Tested-2-year-warranty/392019109457?hash=item5b4628e651:g:y2oAAOSwxAxa0MTS

Comment: Could be a selenium surge suppressor stack.

Comment: It definitely must be multiple "diode" discs, with alternating-bias, to perform the function of a [thyrector](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/definitions/thyrectors-4). Today, we would use a TVS or MOV for this function. Interesting history lesson! I can imagine some poor assembly-line worker counting, flipping, and installing those discs and springs by hand in 1975.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a thyrector, a transient voltage suppresor.

Datasheet : http://docdro.id/eVE6OB5

why (noise)
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is a selenium rectifier.

Google search of the part number points to this.

http://www.parttarget.com/6130-00-136-1416_6130001361416_KZ9DTM.html/-1642D163-C569-435E-881F-72C91B685EF9

```
MRC     Parameter                             Characteristics
---------------------------------------------------------------
AARA    Terminal Quantity                     2
AARB    Terminal Type                         Wire lead
ABHP    Overall Length                        1.600 inches nominal
ADAV    Overall Diameter                      0.575 inches nominal
AJUR    Circuit Connection Style Designator   Half-wave 1 phase
ANPZ    Inclosure Feature                     Plastic case
ASCT    RMS Input Maximum Voltage Rating      270.0 volts
ASCZ    Stack Quantity                        1
ASDS    Grounded Terminal                     Not included
MATT    Material                              Selenium
```